# overcast blank gray button on playing html5 iOS Cordova video

Tags: css, html, cordova, html5-video

I have searched stack overflow, googled, and gone to apple's documentation regarding a problem that I've encountered in my Cordova Html5 iOS 11+ app. The app plays videos. It works fine except there is a gray overcast button on top of the video that should display the iOS icons. The button is simply a gray "blob". This happens when the video is first loaded and then again when it is ended.

It looks like this (Upper left screen corner:
[image: Grayed out button lacking normal video image for iOS]
[image]

I've tried using many css workarounds that I found on stack overflow and also on some of my other searches. I thought that this is/was a css problem, but I'm just at a loss. I can't find anything in the Safari docs. The closest I came was a post regarding a gray background issue when playing video. That was solved using brightness. It didn't work at all for my issue. I also couldn't hide the gray buttons.

The video is standard html5:

```
    <video src="myVideo.mp4" controls poster="myPoster.png" height="auto" width="100%">
</video>
```

Thank you ahead of time for your help. If I need to add more information, I can do that. I just don't want to add things that aren't needed.

-Rachel

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide a sample page where this problem occurs that would make it a lot easier.

I'm pretty sure this should be possible with css though. Maybe not the most "beautiful" way to go at this but what I would do is to find the markup of this element and look what css selectors and rules there are which effect it. Then copy the css selector in your own stylesheet and maybe add some class or id to it to make sure it overrides these rules and then simply add a *display: none;* to it.

Maybe give !important a try too if it doesn't work right away.

In the dev tools you can add css rules directly so you can just go through the elements and add *display: none;* there, to see which element you need to refer to in your file.

But again, it's really hard to tell without an example to look at.

Comment: Does the additional picture of the video help? Video shows this button as soon as the play button is tapped and the video plays. It also shows when the video ends.